# useradd --disabled-password can't ssh using authorized keys

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I might've done this wrong. I created a user with :

```
sudo adduser --disabled-password userX
```

And I've added a public key to `/home/userX/.ssh/authorized_keys`. But when I ssh into the account I get the following error:

```
port 22: Connection timed out
```

SSH works fine when I log into other accounts.

Was I wrong to `--disabled-password`? Does this do something else?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Was I wrong to --disable-password?

No, it seems unlikely this will be causing a timeout.

> Does this do something else?

It does what it says, creates an account with a disabled password.

I would be looking to see if there is a firewall somewhere between you and the server to determine the cause of the Connection timed out message.

Comment: This was correct. Very stupid oversight on my part. I had limited outgoing ssh to certain ip blocks. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting with ssh -vvv to see the debug messages.

If this just happens with this one account, you should see some difference in the verbose output with respect to other users which work.